# Bulk Canadian Postal Codes inside Google Sheet Using Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Sheet with 3000+ Canadian Addresses, Street, City, Province but I don't have the Postal Codes. Is there a way to look these up using Google Places API or in bulk?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen Google maps/places Postal Code data not up to date many a times. The most reliable thing would be using Canada Post AddressComplete (AC). https://www.canadapost-postescanada.ca/ac/ . It may need some digging into if there are AC API's available that return correct postal code from an address.